# Alert on Back Key Press, Confirm Exit

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a windows phone app, and I want to know how to alert and make sure the that user really wants to exit the app on the back key press. Pretty simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume your navigation is set up such that the user can only exit from the first page. If so, in that page, you can override the [OnBackKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onbackkeypress%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event and cancel the button press. I haven't tested this code, but seems like it should work:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?","Exit?", 
                            MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 

    }
}
```

Edit - I'll leave this here as an example of overriding the back button, but the correct answer in this context is to not implement the feature.

Comment: The solution offered by keyboardP will work, however, unless you have a very compelling reason to do this, I would advise against it. The user experience should be uniform across the platform, and in my experience, the only apps that have presented the "are you sure" dialog on the phone have been games. The user knows that if they are at the first page and they hit back, they will exit the app. You would have to have a *VERY* compelling reason before I would agree with doing this, because I don't want apps that don't work as I expect them to work.

Comment: Oh - and I don't like it when games do it, either.  ;)

Comment: Rich makes a good point. The original Facebook app had a warning before exiting, but it could be switched off. Since the update, I don't think you can turn that setting on. IIRC, there's something in the user guidelines that discourages a popup on exit (for non-games), although I may be misremembering that.

Comment: This isn't work, not sure why. It says `CancelEventArgs` is incorrect, as well as `MessageResult`

Comment: Change it to "System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs" or click on CancelEventArgs, and press 'ctrl' and '.' together to import the namespace for it.

Comment: Try changing it to `MessageBoxResult`.

Answer (score 2):

While the previous answer about cancelling OnBackKeyPress may technically work, it could cause your app to fail certification requirements. See the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=VS.92).aspx

5.2.4.2 – Back Button: First Screen
Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an application must close the application.

I would recommend not implementing this functionality.

Comment: Me too. Most times people want to implement this functionality they seem to be approaching the application from a Windows desktop application perspective. The Windows Phone platform is a different experience. Aside from failing the Marketplace requirements, this would create a "Glance-and-G... oh, wait, uh, yeah, I really meant to do that... -Go!" experience. Not so cool.

Comment: The reason I want to put this in is that it seems like you should be able to press the back key to go back, but you can't. So when you press the back key you end up existing the app. I've seen games do this, isn't there a way to do it in a normal app?

Comment: When you're at the first screen, what is "back" if it isn't "out of the app"?  Games are allowed to do this, because the back button is also allowed to be used as a pause button for games, but in a normal app, it is not necessary.  Read Peter Torr's blog on the subject: chrome://coralietab/content/container.html?url=0,http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/10/06/back-means-back-not-forwards-not-sideways-but-back.aspx

Comment: There's really only one screen, it's just an embedded web page. Very simple app, but it's useful. Already been published: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/6be3a355-a128-4cc8-8997-78c7b18e5219 There is a very good reason for me wanting to alert on exit, it seems like you should be able to press back to go back one page, but you can not. It just makes sense to have it alert to say "woah, you probably didn't mean to exit the app." I understand that in most cases this shouldn't be done.

Comment: Rev - if your app wraps a webpage you might want to do some manual managing of the back stack.  You can handle back key presses, then if the user has previously navigated to a new webpage in your app ask the browser to navigate back a page and pack the back keypress as handled. Just make sure that if the user starts your app and hits back without navigating in the browser that you don't handle anything. This technique has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it working. The way the app works I don't think it really makes sense, but I'm willing to try it if you point me in the right direction.